# When Narasimha swamy incarnated? on Trayodashi or Chaturdasi day?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, narasimha

When Narasimha swamy incarnated? on Trayodashi or Chaturdasi day? 
Someone says Chaturdasi and some says different.  which is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Narasimha avatar happened in Vaishakha masa, shukla paksha chaturdashi. The exact date has not been mentioned in scriptures unlike the date for Ramanavami or Krishna Janmashtami. Astrologers give the aforementioned date as Narasimha Jayanthi.